# Flexbox grid proportional scaling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout, it's actually 3 x 3 but I can illustrate with 2 x 2 [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/chrispink/j43wsnfm/3/)

```css
.grid-container {
  width: 480px; /* Max */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.grid-cell {
  flex: 1;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

So that works but the images don't resize as the grid gets smaller, if I add `.grid-cell img { width: 100%;}` the cells all fit on one line. If I take away `.grid-cell {width: 50%;}` the same happens.

Strangely, in Firefox my desired effect is achieved; the grid shrinks proportionately. In Chrome and Safari, even with -webkit- syntax, it behaves as above. The height of each cell remains constant as the grid gets narrower and the image overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `width: 33%` try `flex: 0 0 33%`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  background: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"><img src="http://www.bathfringe.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/street-icon.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, pulling flex apart that means "don't shrink in relation to your siblings, don't grow.... but take up 33% of the space" ? Thank you. Obvious when you see it. I couldn't find anything else on proportional grid systems so maybe this question can stand.

Comment: Yes and if you maybe want 2 images grid you just use `flex: 0 0 50%` and so on https://jsfiddle.net/j43wsnfm/6/. And with `width: 100%` image will fit in flex item.